# C#, Split scanned image and find content area

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

And again question about image processing :)

With help of AForge.Net I've rotated and cropped scanned image of a book. And now i need to split result of rotating and cropping into separate pages. I need somehow to find line between 2 pages and split image by it. I could just split by middle, but there is an opportunity that there will be scanned images with only one full page and a piece of another.

Then i need to find content area box (box which will include all page's content eg text, images).

I don't know which way i should go to make all these things.

My program should behave just like famous Scan Tailor but with opportunity to skip steps and on C#.

Comment: Can you post an image of both cases: 1) where it is acceptable to split by middle 2) where it is unacceptable to split by middle?

Comment: 1) http://i.piccy.info/i5/07/40/934007/middle.jpg

Comment: 2) I don't really have it. A scanned image will look like when you scan only one page from a book and there is little piece of another page.